# Popunder run automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that inserts a popunder into all the links on my page.
However, I need something that makes this popunder / tabunder run automatically, regardless of the click.
I've tried in many ways but I can't.
Can someone help me?

```
        window.onload = function() {
        var puURL = 'http://google.com';
        var puTS = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
        console.log('T.'+localStorage.puTS+'/'+puTS);
        if (typeof localStorage.puTS == 'undefined' || parseInt(localStorage.puTS) <= (puTS - 3600)) {
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
                links[i].onclick = function (e) {
                    var puHref = this.getAttribute("href");
                    var puTarget = this.getAttribute("target");
                    if (puHref !== '#' && puHref !== 'javascript:void(0)') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (puTarget == '_blank') {
                            window.open(window.location.href);
                        }
                        window.open(puHref);
                        window.location.href = puURL;
                        localStorage.puTS = puTS;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you tell us if your script is internal or external? In other words, if it's loaded from a distinct directory or is stored within the HTML file? If within the HTML file, then where exactly is your script tag placed, in the header or under the body tag etc?

Comment: You can open your DEV TOOLS in the browser and head to the console section to check if there are any issues involving the script call.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed your script locally under the HEAD Tag section and the function is triggered when I open the HTML file. I assume that the issue lays in the script placement.

If your script is stored outside the project (is external), make sure that you navigate to the correct root and double-check for spelling. Here is an example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="project/javascript_folder/myscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

You can check out [W3Schools File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_filepaths.asp) for more detail.

---

If you open your browsers *DEV-TOOLS* (by pressing the Right-Click button on your mouse while you hover over the page) and navigate to the console section, you should see the successful output from your function:

In my case, it is `T.undefined/...` where "..." represents a randomly generated number in the length of 10.

[image]